# How do I animate after presentModalViewController finishes sliding?

Tags: ios, core-animation, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am showing a login screen with an error, like:

```
_loginViewController.error = error;
[_navigationController presentModalController: _loginViewController
                                     animated: YES];
```

In LoginViewController, I want to slide the error message onto the screen like this:

```
- (void)showErrorAnimated: (BOOL)animated;
{
    _errorLabel.text = [_error localizedDescription];

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"showError"
                    context: NULL];
    CGRect frame = [_errorView frame];
    frame.origin.y = 0; // starts at -frame.size.height
    [_errorView setFrame: frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But I don't know how to call this to match the timing of the view controller **finishing** it's slide to the top of the screen begun by `presentModalController:animated:`.

How can I get this timing working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `viewDidAppear` method of your controller, which will be called the time the view is displayed.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW17

Just be careful with `viewDidAppear` because it is called whenever your view is shown. This means that if your controller presents a modal controller and then it is dismissed, the `viewWillAppear`and `viewDidAppear` methods will be called again.

Comment: I'm playing with this, but in addition to the redisplay wrinkle it requires me to use `[UIView setAnimationDelay:]` to delay the animation some magic, undocumented time. I'd really prefer to avoid that.

Comment: Oh. I might be entirely wrong about having to delay it. (Don't bother checking, I'm doing so.)

Comment: actually, if your coding to ios 4 you should use the methods provided by it, such as `animateWithDuration:animations:`  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111

Comment: I'm converting it to the newer style now. Thanks for that pointer, too. This is my first iOS 4 project. :)